# How to get time by this string in javascript 2017-11-29T10:27:15.2327188Z

Tags: javascript

I have this string 2017-11-29T10:27:15.2327188Z I just need to get time in javascript any idea how ?

Comment: The time is 10:27:15 Zulu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will get your local time from the string.

```js
var x = '2017-11-29T10:27:15.2327188Z'
var d = new Date(x);
var time = d.getHours() + ':' +  d.getMinutes() +  ':' +  d.getSeconds()
console.log(time)
```

Comment: is it possible we can get it in am and pm also ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206453/best-way-to-convert-military-time-to-standard-time-in-javascript this post has code to change the military time to standard time.

Answer (score 2):

First, convert the string into a date object:

```
var date = new Date('2017-11-29T10:27:15.2327188Z');
```

Then, you can call `toLocaleTimeString()` to return a string with a language sensitive representation of the time portion of this date:

```
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
```

Comment: Awesome,Working perfect

Comment: @niteshSharma Glad to help!